# How to compare test-coverage value with specific threshold for Golang test cases

Tags: bash, go, makefile

I want to get the test coverage and compare with user defined threshold. I tried below code in makefile I am referring this [link](https://medium.com/synechron/how-to-set-up-a-test-coverage-threshold-in-go-and-github-167f69b940dc). It is written in .yml file but I am trying to write it in a Makefile.

```
.PHONY: lint    
testcoverage=$(go tool cover -func coverage.out | grep total | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
echo ${testcoverage}
if (${testcoverage} -lt 50 ); then \
  echo "Please add more unit tests or adjust threshold to a lower value."; \
  echo "Failed"
  exit 1
else \
  echo "OK"; \
fi
```

It does not print anything on `echo ${totaltestcoverage}` and gives answer OK even if my totaltestcoverage is 40.

Can anyone please help me with a better way to get the test coverage and compare with user defined threshold?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
.PHONY: lint

testcoverage := $(shell go tool cover -func=coverage.out | grep total | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
threshold = 50

test:
    @go test -coverprofile=coverage.out -covermode=count  ./...

check-coverage:
    @echo "Test coverage: $(testcoverage)"
    @echo "Test Threshold: $(threshold)"
    @echo "-----------------------"

    @if [ "$(shell echo "$(testcoverage) < $(threshold)" | bc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then \
        echo "Please add more unit tests or adjust the threshold to a lower value."; \
        echo "Failed"; \
        exit 1; \
    else \
        echo "OK"; \
    fi
```

- [What does @: (at symbol colon) mean in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610799/what-does-at-symbol-colon-mean-in-a-makefile)
- [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)

Comment: Hi @PRATHEESH PC thank you so much for you help. I am getting this output 
`/bin/bash: line 1: bc: command not found
ok   github.XXXXX.com/org/repo 0.027s coverage: 47.2% of statements
Test coverage: 
Test Threshold: 
/bin/bash: line 1: [: : integer expression expected
OK`

Comment: I get this output on github while running in CI

Comment: How did your `yaml` look like ? Which `os` you are using ? See the demo at here https://github.com/pcpratheesh/unite-test-coverage

Comment: I have this in yml file 
jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, docker, internet]

Comment: Hoping you are running the pipline with your own runner, and you may need to install the `bc`. Hope this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/550985/installing-bc-and-any-maths-extension

Comment: I dont have ubuntu-latest in my runs-on[] I can not use it.